# Total Busy time in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

There are auto generated statistics in VANET where I am able to see the total busy time for each node among other things such as the send packets and received broadcasts. Is this time in seconds or milliseconds? What does this mean exactly to have the total busy time for each node

Note: I am using Omnet 5.0, Sumo-0.25.0 and Veins-4.4, TraCIDemo11p.cc

[image: a screenshot of my simulation]